# Compiling CUDA code when a cublas function is called inside the kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, cublas

I am trying to run a very simple kernel which calls cublassgemm function. My code is:

```
__global__ void cor (float * dev_mat,float * dev_cor,int n,cublasHandle_t handle)
{
        const float alpha = 1.0;
        const float beta = 0;
        cublasStatus_t stat;
        stat = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N,  CUBLAS_OP_N, n, n, n,  &alpha, dev_mat, n, dev_mat,n,&beta, dev_cor, n);
        if(stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
                {
                        cout<<"error in cublas sgemm \n";
                }
}
int main()
{
int  m =1000,n = 1000;
float * h_mat = new float[m*n];
float * h_cor = new float[m*n];
float * dev_mat,*dev_cor;
cudaMalloc(&dev_mat,m*n*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc(&dev_cor,m*n*sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i< m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <n;j++)
                {
                        h_mat[i*n+j]=rand()%10;
                }
cudaError_t cudaStat;
cublasStatus_t stat;
cublasHandle_t handle;
stat = cublasSetMatrix(m, n, sizeof(float), h_mat, m, dev_mat, m);
if(stat !=CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
                cout<<"error in cublassetmatrix   \n";
                return stat;
        }
stat = cublasCreate (&handle);
if(stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
                cout<<"error in cublas create handle \n";
                return stat;
        }

cor<<<1,1>>>(dev_mat,dev_cor,n,handle);
cudaFree(dev_mat);
delete []h_mat;
delete []h_cor;
return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this code using the following command:

> nvcc -lcublas cublassegmm_inside_kernel.cu -o
>   cublassegmm_inside_kernel

But I got the following error:

> calling a **host** function("std::operator << >
>   ") from a **global** function("cor") is not allowed

I read [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462779/call-cublas-in-a-kernel) but I didn't understand how should I compile! Can anyone please explain to me or suggest a source.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues (at least):

1. You can't use `cout` in a CUDA kernel.  Change it to an equivalent `printf` statement and you should be OK:

   ```
   printf("error in cublas sgemm \n");
   ```
2. Your compile command is incorrect.  The link you gave shows the necessary components.  You should use something like this:

   ```
   nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -o cublassgemm_inside_kernel cublassgemm_inside_kernel.cu -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt
   ```

And of course this will only work on a cc3.5 or higher GPU.