# Using cublas GEMM in a Python CUDA kernel

Tags: python, cuda, cublas

I have a simple matrix-matrix multiplication code as below:

```
TPB = 32
@cuda.jit('void(double[:, :], double[:,:], double[:, :])', device = True)
def GPU_Mat2(A, B, C):
    bx = cuda.blockIdx.x
    by = cuda.blockIdx.y
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    ty = cuda.threadIdx.y
    ROW = bx * TPB + tx
    COL = by * TPB + ty
    res = 0

    for k in range(A.shape[1]):
        if ROW < A.shape[0] and COL < B.shape[1]:
           res += A[ROW, k] * B[k, COL]
    cuda.syncthreads()

    if ROW < A.shape[0] and COL < B.shape[1]:
       C[ROW, COL] = res
    cuda.syncthreads()
```

and then I call this function in another kernel twice.

```
@cuda.jit('void(double[:, :], double[:,:], double[:, :], double[:, :])')
def call_Mat2(A, B, C, D):
    for _ in range(200):
        GPU_Mat2(A, B, C)
        GPU_Mat2(C, B, D)        # Is this correct?
```

Unfortunately, this procedure does not give me the correct answer when compared to the same calculation in host. Even when I use cuda.syncthreads() after each GPU_Mat2 call, the answer is still wrong. My question is that "is it possible to use the output of a kernel call (here C) in another kernel as an input?"

```
def main():
N = 300
A = np.asfortranarray(np.random.random_sample((N,N)))
B = np.asfortranarray(np.random.random_sample((N,N)))
C_GPU = np.zeros((N,N), dtype = np.double, order = 'F')
D_GPU = np.zeros((N,N), dtype = np.double, order = 'F')

numThreads = [TPB, TPB]
numBlocks =[(A.shape[0]+TPB-1)//TPB, (B.shape[1]+TPB-1)//TPB]

d_A = cuda.to_device(A)
d_B = cuda.to_device(B)
d_C = cuda.to_device(C_GPU)
d_D = cuda.to_device(D_GPU)

call_Mat2[numBlocks, numThreads](d_A, d_B, d_C, d_D)
```

Second, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462779/call-cublas-in-a-kernel), it is possible to call "blas GEMM" in a kernel, but I could not find a similar example in python script. Is this type of call supported by python?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/kernels.html):

> Note: newer CUDA devices support device-side kernel launching; this feature is called dynamic parallelism but Numba does not support it currently)

So no, you cannot call other device library or `@cuda.jit` functions in numba compiled CUDA Python at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @talonmies

Comment: @Soroushm: If you wouldn't mind accepting this answer, the question will fall off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag and the result will be easier for the next person to find by searching. Thanks